# How to share with specify Title,image,Details on facebook in MVC4 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been searched on google so many time about facebook share and comment,but i didn't see any good solution for me.I try to share my product with my code

```
<a class="facebook"rel="nofollow"  target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@Param&p[images][0]=@Model.Imgurl&p[title]=@Model.Name&p[summary]=@Model.Description">
```

With my param in my url of products detail.It just share the link without configure my description.Any solution for me.

And please tell me how can i create comment in facebook too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you set from the link Facebook needs some [open graph/meta tags](http://kadiravci.com/Article/Details/23) for that.

Also check your url with Facebook url linter to make sure everything is ok.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug